# What is reason for sql result set couldn't return result set?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, return, return-type

I'm trying to return result set some method. I'm sure that my sql query out put some result set. Because in the "while(rs.next())" method I print the values. But problem is when I'm returning that result set values and try to calling "while(rs.next())" in the calling method that doesn't print any value. What is reason for that?

/* Calling method */

```
    public void corpusRetriveDemo(){
    ArrayList<String> wordAll= new ArrayList<String>();
            /* Get all word list For corpus Retrive */
    wordAll=allWordsList(sentence1);
    ResultSet rsNew=corpusSentenceRetrive(wordAll);


    try {
        while (rsNew.next()) {
            System.out.println("Heloooo2...");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /* uni Gram calculate */

    double d1=calculateProbUniGram(wordAll,rsNew);
    System.out.println(d1);

}
```

/* Database retrieve method */

```
    public ResultSet corpusSentenceRetrive(List wordList) {
    PreparedStatement pstmtFGram = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    ResultSet rs2 = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        conn = getConnection();
        sb.append("SELECT Cor_Sentence FROM corpus Where ");
             for(int k=0;k<wordList.size();k++){
                 sb.append( " Cor_Sentence like '%" + wordList.get(k) + "%' OR ");
             } 
                 sb.append(" 1=0"); 
                 pstmtFGram = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString());

            rs2 = pstmtFGram.executeQuery();
            while (rs2.next()) {
                System.out.println("Heloo1...");
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return rs2;

}
```

"Heloo1" printing correctly. But calling method "Helooo2" doesn't print. What is reason for that? Is there anything wrong with my return statement?

Comment: and what 'allWordsList' function does? what is the value of 'wordAll'?

Comment: @ymz That gives list of values. That returns array list. I'm sure that sql function(corpusSentenceRetrive) calling and returns value set to "rs2".

Comment: @MiyaG Not any exception. Doesn't print any thing in calling method inside wile statement.("Helooo2") But huge ("Helooo1" ) set prints.

Comment: @Maduri find below answer given by me

Comment: @Maduri read my answer for explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your question you are appending  string to string builder.

One thing thing is that. At last final string become look like.

```
SELECT Cor_Sentence FROM corpus Where  Cor_Sentence like '%" + wordList.get(k) + "%' OR Cor_Sentence like '%" + wordList.get(k) + "%' OR
```

Due to sql query is It trowing an exception.

Another way you are saying **Helloo1** is printing. So please comment below line in your code and test.

```
 while (rs2.next()) {
            System.out.println("Heloo1...");
                    }
```

Comment: Now huge "Helooo2" printing(calling method) .What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I'm not the person down vote. Sorry anyone else may be. Why I couldn't put while statement. Why should I comment that?

Comment: @Maduri see my answer for explanation

Comment: @Maduri once result set executed you can't execute that again.

Comment: @Miya G I'm new to stack overflow. Sorry I has clicked that vote button. Now I think ok. I got the point. I think reason is result set come to last and empty one return to calling method. Thanx lot. Have a nice day :).

Answer (score 2):

Remove

```
while (rs2.next()) {
      System.out.println("Heloo1...");
}
```

from the database retrieve method.

You are using the same result set in both cases, and you already reached the end of it by the time you want to print Hello2.

`rsNew.next()` doesn't have any where to iterate further anymore in your calling method, since it already reached it's end in the database retrieve method.

Answer (score 0):

when working with **RecordSet** the proper approach is this:

```
rs.first();

do
{
  // do something here

} while (rs.next());
```

**the reason**: after iteration on the set it position is at the end of the set, thus making the next method return false. first positioning it back at the beginning

### A RECORDSET CAN BE ITERATED MORE THEN ONCE

also  seems like **you never close the connection** conn... please try this please:

```
try {
    conn = getConnection();
    sb.append("SELECT Cor_Sentence FROM corpus Where ");
         for(int k=0;k<wordList.size();k++){
             sb.append( " Cor_Sentence like '%" + wordList.get(k) + "%' OR ");
         } 
             sb.append(" 1=0"); 
             pstmtFGram = conn.prepareStatement(sb.toString());

        rs2 = pstmtFGram.executeQuery();
        while (rs2.next()) {
            System.out.println("Heloo1...");
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
finally
{
   if (conn != null) conn.close();
}
```

Comment: that won't fix his problem, he already iterated through the resultset before calling it in the other method. Sure, closing the connection is good practice, but please answer the question asked, and not the question you want.